# How does swagger works with immutableMap (with different type of values) response?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have some APIs which returns the following response. How can I use swagger to do the documentation? I know swagger responseContainer supports Map, but the value type of the map seems to have to be the same type. But in my case, the values are in different type: foos is type of List, and the second key "count" corresponds to integer.

```
Response.ok(ImmutableMap.of("result", foos, "count", foos.size())).build();
```

The response of the API is something like this:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "f1": "v1",
      "f2": "v2"
    },
    {
      "f1": "v3",
      "f2": "v4"
    }
  ],
  "count": 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response can be described like this:

```
definitions:
  MyResponse:
    type: object
    required:
      - result
      - count
    properties:
      result:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Foo'
      count:
        type: integer

  Foo:
    type: object
    additionalProperties:
      type: string
```